# Feature request: Remind the asker to accept a helpful answer.

Tags: feature-request

I make this request for two reasons:

First: I find it rather annoying to answer someone's question and be thanked in a comment, while not getting the answer acceptance.

Second: It's also annoying to click on an interesting question, that apparently has not been answered well enough as to satisfy the asker, only to find out (by reading the comments) that the asker is in fact already satisfied with the existing answers, but simply not accepted any.

In my experience, most of the times this happens when the asker is new around; let's remind them to (or let them know they can/should) accept a helpful answer. Let's put a nice pop-up, or a simple legend, as a reminder of that, maybe when we are writing the question or right after posting it.

Comment: This exists http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers If you want some modification of the existing behavior you should be more explicity.

Comment: A major drawback of the current pop-up notification is that it shows up only when the user upvotes, and new users typically can't vote. A thing worth considering is to show this pop-up message when a new user leaves a comment containing "thank".

Comment: Don't sweat it! This site is about helping people, not (primarily) about gaining reputation. Just let the new users find these things out for themselves, and be glad you were able to help them on the way.

Comment: Also in the list of questions a text *"Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"* is shown for low-rep users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a pop-up.  Unfortunately, it only pops up when you're on the page (IIRC--it's been a while since I asked a question).  A work-around is to `@`-notify the user to remind them that they can accept an answer--I sometimes do this if the OP is brand-new to the site.

I would think that an inbox notification (if they don't accept an answer within a day or so of one being posted) would be helpful for some new users, but I've kinda decided to "just live with it."  It's a fact of life that you won't get all the rep you think you may deserve.

Comment: I agree. There will be "drive by" users who forget to accept, but most of the repeat users will learn fairly soon.